# Update multiple columns from select that have more columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update 2 columns from a given query but the problem is that the query has more than 2 columns, so this is the correct syntax if I take off the additional columns :

```
UPDATE myTable TAO 
  SET (TAO.BASE_AMT,TAO.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) = ( 
 SELECT SUM(decode(TAX_CD_VAT_PCT 
 , 0 
 , 0 
 ,d.monetary_amount)) 
 , MAX (D.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) 
  FROM ps_VCHR_LINE_WTHD w 
  , PS_DISTRIB_LINE d 
 WHERE 1=1 
 -- some conditions
  GROUP BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id 
  ORDER BY 1, 2)
```

The Original query is like that:

```
 SELECT d.business_unit, d.voucher_id,SUM(decode(TAX_CD_VAT_PCT 
 , 0 
 , 0 
 ,d.monetary_amount)) 
 , MAX (D.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) 
  FROM ps_VCHR_LINE_WTHD w 
  , PS_DISTRIB_LINE d 
 WHERE 1=1 
 -- some conditions
  GROUP BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id 
  ORDER BY 1, 2)
```

So if I remove `d.business_unit, d.voucher_id` will I have the same result? because I tried this in SQL developer when I remove it I don't get the same top rows.

Can someone Help?

Thanks.

Comment: There's all sorts of horribleness going on there!  Are you really updating a table based on a query that returns multiple values, and expecting the `ORDER BY` clause to "sort this all out"?

Comment: That traditional practices of not using joins is an issue definitely, Not ANSI-92 standard, use join instead of commas

Comment: If you want the same result as before then you will probably need to change `ORDER BY 1, 2` to `ORDER BY d.business_unit, d.voucher_id`.  But I would strongly recommend rethinking your approach here.

Comment: give us sample data and expected result. if you remove the 2 columns you mentioned then the sum is different.

Comment: your question ends in a very different way than it begins. what exactly are you asking for ? what is your aim ? select it or update it ?

Comment: @Doruk Yes you are right i ask if there is a better way than this if not will  removing the additional columns resolve that or not  because i don't get the same result when i tested it ?

Comment: @RichardHansell I tried what you say and i got the same top rows will this resolve my problem ? Thank you

Comment: i still don't understand. resolve what ? what is the problem ?

Comment: @Doruk if you look to the original query you will see that it's based on the first 2 columns `d.business_unit, d.voucher_id` but what i need to update is the last 2 columns so i have to delete the firts columns like in my first example , and when i put the query like that in SQLDevelopper i don't get the same top rows so i am confused if i have the good result or not

Comment: How about doing the update from a subquery that has the group by? [Like in this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692077/update-with-group-by)

Comment: Changing the `ORDER BY` is simply making your update query the same as the original select query was.  It should fix your problem, but it's not really a good solution.  Using MERGE, sub-queries, common table expressions, even temporary tables would all be better solutions imho.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement. It is difficult to determine how you are correlating your update statement to the nested select (it doesn't seem that there is any correlation) but, assuming it is on the `business_unit` and `voucher_id` columns then something like:

```
MERGE INTO my_table dst
USING (
  SELECT d.business_unit,
         d.voucher_id,
         SUM( DECODE( TAX_CD_VAT_PCT, 0, 0, d.monetary_amount ) ) AS total_tax_cd_vat_pct,
         MAX (D.TAX_CD_VAT_PCT) AS max_tax_cd_vat_pct
  FROM   ps_VCHR_LINE_WTHD w 
         INNER JOIN
         PS_DISTRIB_LINE d 
         ON ( /* some conditions here */ )
  WHERE  1=1
         -- some conditions
  GROUP BY
         d.business_unit,
         d.voucher_id
) src
ON (
      src.business_unit = dst.business_unit
  AND src.voucher_id    = dst.voucher_id
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
   BASE_AMT       = src.total_tax_cd_vat_pct
   TAX_CD_VAT_PCT = src.max_tax_cd_vat_pct;
```